# Make the entire bottom div resizeable, rather than just the text box

Tags: feature-request, chat, user-interface

You can currently only resize the text box in chat. Given that there's only a few pixels below the text box, this resizing doesn't help all that much.

[image]

Would it be possible to make the entire bottom `div` resizeable, rather than just the text box (with the height of the text box dependent on the height of the `div`)?

(No longer suggesting resizing the textbox *itself* upwards, as this doesn't appear to be a possibility)

Comment: That's a browser thing - not a chat thing.

Comment: What does it do on other browsers (I'm using Chrome)? But isn't there like a CSS option or something that would change this?

Comment: No... no there is none that I know of.... Sorry @Dukeling

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize - nothing there :(

Comment: @Oded There may still be a work-around, like making the entire bottom panel resizeable. Not sure how clean that would look if we want horizontal scrolling as well, but why do we want that, why not just make the text box the max (ok-looking) horizontal size (as a function of the screen size, obviously)?

Comment: @Dukeling Not all browsers have that resize thing. The one you are showing is Chrome exclusive...

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA Modified question to request allowing resizing of the `div` instead. Some browsers don't allow resizing - there's not much we can (easily) do about that.